# adding/renaming an id on click

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
if (el.nodeName == 'IMG'){

  e1.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
           el.id = this.src;});
}
```

any idea why this doesn't work when I click on the image?

Comment: How are you confirming that this does not work?  And where does `el` come from?

Comment: You have to post more of your code and create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. There could be a lot of problems, e.g. you could be attaching the event handler in a loop. But what I immediately see is that you are calling `addEventListener` on `e1` (e-one) instead of `el` and note that Firefox requires a third parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`e1` vs `el` the second one is an L not a 1 (one).